# Django Rest Framework: not showing latest records unless i restart the server

Tags: django, caching, django-rest-framework

I'm using django rest framework, to create and retrieve records, but I noticed that when I create a new record and then try to fetch the list of records it doesn't show in the list of records even after 24h, unless I restart the gunicorn server.

I think it has something to do with caching, but I didn't find anything intresting in the documentation about caching.

I want to keep the caching as it is good for performance... but I want the new records to show, is there anyway to refresh the cache after a record is added? or anything similar?

Comment: We cannot help you unless you post some code, one of the reason it could be is that you are using module/class level attribute for queryset which only gets reloaded when you restart your code.

Comment: @JamesLin yes you are right that was the case, and I fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use method_decorator and cache_page in your get or list method of views

at the first you must import its

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
```

Example:

```
class CLASSNAME(APIView):

    # Cache page for the requested url
    @method_decorator(cache_page(60*60*2))  # 2 hour
    def get(self, request, format=None):

        """ Your codes """

class CLASSNAME(viewsets.ViewSet):

    # Cache requested url for each user for 2 hours
    @method_decorator(cache_page(60*60*2))
    def list(self, request, format=None):
        """ Your codes """
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: i have seen this in the documentation, this sets the caching per view, but it didn't fix the missing records.